# Closure Compiler: How to separate and control compilation/minification passes?

Tags: javascript, obfuscation, compiler-optimization, google-closure-compiler, deobfuscation

The Google Closure Compiler is a powerful compiler and minifier for JS, which gives a lot of optimization options such as renaming variables, removing dead codes, collapsing variable declarations, rewriting control flow structures and etc.

What I want is to separately apply one or some of these optimizations on an input JS program. For example, I may want to rename variables with short names, but not to remove dead codes. How can I achieve this kind of detailed compilation pass control? Does the source code of CC expose specific interfaces to do this customization, or I should write my own pass(If so, how am I supposed to start?).

The command line features do offer several options for controlling the compilation, but are insufficient to fit what I want above. Since the source code is kinda complicated and few detailed design documentation can be found, I am truly stuck here. Any insights would be appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [DefaultPassConfig](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/master/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/DefaultPassConfig.java). That class lists all the passes that are run during the compilation, based on what options are set in the CompilerOptions. Some of the CompilerOptions can be controlled from the command line, but we generally try to keep the compiler relatively simple and easy to use, and not ask users to make decisions about a bunch of different compiler flags. Plus, there are some passes that actually *increase* the code size, but they do it in such a way that it makes it easier for some later pass to decrease it afterwards.

Of course if you're just experimenting with the compiler or trying to understand how it works, you can turn on and off whichever passes you want, either by adding new flags, or just modifying DefaultPassConfig directly.

Comment: Many of the flags are controlled by [CompilationLevel.java](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/master/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/CompilationLevel.java). Sometimes it's easier to modify those options.

Comment: By the way, a few members of the team tend to check the Stack Overflow `google-closure-compiler` tag and the mailing list pretty often, so there's no need to post the same question in both places.